# How to handle failures from a Restful webservice calls in iOS Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, rest, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking` to call webservices from the app. Everything is working fine. Since I am new to iOS development, I made things work somehow but I want to learn the proper way of implementing stuffs and handle various conditions.

Below is the `AFNetwork` working **code:**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:url parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

When I make a service call, if the call fails(due to poor network connectivity) then in the failure block how do I handle it? Suppose it is an important service call like **login service** then I cannot give up and need to call the service again.. I browsed a lot but everywhere they just show the UIAlert saying there is not connectivity. But I donot want to use alerts if the call fails for the first time...

Should I call the service with some time delay or is there any other solution? If any of you have handled this kind of situation better please do reply...

Comment: Generally login web service is not auto triggered on failure. We simply show a popup asking the user to try again later. Or we may show a popup like 'Network Failure. Do you want to try logging in again?' with 2 options yes-no. If user hits yes, you call the web service again.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we simply show the toast or alert for the error and do the processing accordingly. If you see in your failure block there are 2 parameters AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation & NSError *error. Based on the status code you can add you logic inside the failure block. I have added the sample code

List of status codes :- [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes](http://Link)

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager POST:url parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"Success");
 }
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSInteger statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;
     if(statusCode == 401) {
        //Add your logic
     } else if (statusCode == 404) {
        //Add your logic
     }
 }];
```

Comment: It seems, in your failure handler code, you make the assumption that the network request returned a response - and thus succeeded. You ignore the possibility, that you didn't get a response at all. This is the case when the host is not reachable. Only due to the peculiarity of the Objective-C language, the statement `operation.response.statusCode` will return `0` when the response is `nil`. Note also, that you may get any HTTP status code in the success handler.